Se carga el home por un instante cuando navego a cualquier ruta en mi servidor de Nginx
En mi servidor Nginx estoy desplegando mi app Angular con la opción de compilación SSG para prerenderizar las rutas existentes en conjunto con la implementación de la carga diferida de módulos, (es importante recalcar que cada vista es un módulo), por lo que al implementarse SSG con prerrender no quedan compilados archivos index.html sino archivos .js que corresponden a dichos módulos.
Al momento de desplegar mi aplicación que sirve archivos estáticos, al navegar a cualquier ruta, aparece el componente del home por un segundo, y luego la vista a la cual estoy navegando.

Cuando reviso el network y hago la petición de la vista de contacto me llega inicialmente la vista del home, y muchas veces también me aparece la vista del wildcard, ¿cómo puedo lograr que al ingresar a una ruta me redireccione al componente sin tener que pasar por el home o el wildcard?

Este es mi configuración de rutas:
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./modules/home/home.module').then(
        (m) => m.HomeModule
      ),
  },
  {
    path: 'contacto',
    component: ContactanosComponent,
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./modules/contactanos/contactanos.module').then(
        (m) => m.ContactanosModule
      ),
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: NotFoundComponent,
  }
];


Y este es la configuración de mi vHost:
  location ~ /.well-known {
    auth_basic off;
    allow all;
  }

  index index.html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /;
  }

  location ~* ^.+\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|gz|svg|svgz|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|eot|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|webp|zip|swf)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
    expires max;
    access_log off;
  }
}

